# small issue with JS counter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying pick a specific image to display according to the URL i get passed from prev page, 
i get one of the 3 urls, http://domain.com/mobile.html/#0 or 1 or 2
i need to add 1 to the number and send the appropriate image, for some reason i get the false images for image 0, and for image 2 and 3 i get the -1 image (1&2).

something is wrong with the counter i try to create and i can't figure what.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var numb = document.URL.substr(document.URL.indexOf('#')+1);
        $('[name=mobileBar]').val(numb);
        $('.couponImage').attr('src','img/bar'+numb+'.png');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var numb = parseInt(document.URL.substr(document.URL.indexOf('#')+1),10)+1;
        $('[name=mobileBar]').val(numb);
        $('.couponImage').attr('src','img/bar'+numb+'.png');
    });
</script>
```

Notice the `+1` at the end of the first line. It seems like you're confused with `document.URL.indexOf('#')+1`. This `+1` is to increase the index by 1 and sub string from there, not add 1 to the extracted number.

Comment: Don't forget the radix argument to `parseInt`!

Comment: @Amit Sonnenschein: did you use parseInt (in my answer)?

Comment: @Bergi: thanks for pointing out. In his case, there is 1 case starting with "0". It's better to specify the radix.

Comment: @KhanhTO No i didn't, as i'm not very experienced with js can you show me ?

Comment: @Amit Sonnenschein:You should use parseInt, otherwise it's a string concatenation, not an addition. check out my updated answer with radix argument (10) to the parseInt method.

Comment: @Amit Sonnenschein: the reason why there is a string concatenation is because document.URL.substr(document.URL.indexOf('#')+1) returns a string. When you call document.URL.substr(document.URL.indexOf('#')+1) + 1. The 1 will be converted to string automatically. It's equivalent to document.URL.substr(document.URL.indexOf('#')+1) + "1"

Comment: @KhanhTO the last revision actually worked, i didn't think about the string limitation.. i though i can just ++ it from N to N+1.. 
anyway, thanks a lot - it was exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you don't add 1 to the counter... This should work

```
var numb = document.URL.substr(document.URL.indexOf('#')+1);
numb = parseInt(numb,10) + 1;
```

Comment: This one generates 01, 11 & 21 for some reason

Comment: @Amit Sonnenschein: because without parseInt. It will be string concatenation, not an addition.

Comment: Yeah, correct. Updated, thanks! The second argument 10 is the base of the conversion, e.g. if you used 2, it would convert to binary, and if you used 8 it would convert to octal.